# finding sum of squares of column using for each

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie. I want to sum the squares of the numbers in the active column. I am getting an error 'object doesn't support this method'. Here is my code

```
Sub sum_squares()
Dim total As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

'set d equal to column from active cell down to last non-empty'
d = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.endxldown)
total = 0
For Each c In d
   total = total + c.Value ^ 2
Next c

End Sub
```

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: `.End(xlDown)` - `endxldown` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out you've got the syntax of `xlDown` incorrect.
You should also start at the bottom and move up - `xlDown` may not find the last cell.

E.g.

- With a value in cell `A1:A3` and `A1` as the `ActiveCell` it will correctly return `A3`.
- Same scenario but with `A4` left blank and a value in `A5` still returns `A3`.
- Same scenario with `A1` left blank it returns `A2`.

This will return a reference from the `ActiveCell` to the last cell containing a value in that column.
Note that if the `ActiveCell` is lower down than the last cell containing data you'll get a reference reflecting that.

```
Set d = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp))
```

---

A `Range` can be made up of one or more cell references:

- `Range("A1")` and `Range("A1,A3,C5")` reference individual cells.
- `Range("A1:C5")` and `Range("A1", "C5")` reference all cells between the first and last address.

A `Cell` is a single cell reference that uses row and columns identifiers.

- `Cells("A1")` will return an error as it's a full address.
- `Cells(1,"A")` will return `A1` (row 1, column A)
- `Cells(1,1)` will also return `A1` (row 1, column 1)

The code above is using two cell addresses to reference all cells between the two.

- `Range(ActiveCell,....)` is the reference to the first cell.
- `Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column)` is the reference to the second cell using row numbers and column numbers.
  If the `ActiveCell` is in column B then this is the same as writing `Cells(1048573,2)`.
  The `End(xlUp)` then goes from that cell back up to the first one containing data.

Comment: Please can you explain the code there? Specifically Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column)

Comment: I see so rows.count refers to the last row of excel. Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  You can hard code the number if you prefer as long as you're not going to be using it on an Excel 2003 or less version - it will throw an error with less rows.  You might also want to look into avoiding `ActiveCell` and `Select` in VBA by fully qualifying your range references [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code - `.endxldown` and add `Set` before assigning range.

Correct it to -
`Set d = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)`

Comment: thank you so much. So is d an object because it does not change whearas c is a variable because its what we're looping through?

Comment: Both `c` and `d` are variables referencing objects. `c` holds a reference to a single cell within the range of `d`.

Comment: so why does d need a 'set' but not c?

Comment: I knew you were going to ask that next which is why I nearly didn't add the first comment.  I honestly don't know except to say that `For Each Set C in D` doesn't sound right.